# Error configparse some unknown option in read_database_uri

Tags: database-connection, uri, configparser

I try to run sql query in python, but got this error today:
Called result::unwrap() on Err Value: Error {kind:configParse, cause:some(unknown option(“part of my uri link)
But I did run this same code before without problem. Can you help me look at what’s wrong

Tried to check the uri password and database connection everything

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.